# Should I minify node_modules or should I use the minified version provided for deploy on client?

Tags: minify, node-modules, webpack

I recently moved to webpack from require.js and some node_module have .min files built in. When I use a file from node_module I just do `require('my-module')` and it loads it right away without any config. But this will load the development version or a bigger version.

For example react is loaded `require('react/addons')` but this is not the minified version.

My question is:

- Should I load modules normally and then minify everything?
- Should I use their .min files provided and then minify everything again? (in this way I save a lot of disk)
- Any better way? Would be nice to automatically loade minified files.

For now, I'm changing the aliases of webpack to load the minified version when building the app:

```
myConfig.resolve.alias.phaserUnFixed = "nodeModules/phaser/build/custom/phaser-no-physics.min.js";
myConfig.resolve.alias.react = "nodeModules/react/dist/react-with-addons.min.js";
myConfig.resolve.alias.lodash = "nodeModules/lodash/dist/lodash.compat.min.js";
myConfig.resolve.alias.moment = "nodeModules/moment/min/moment.min.js";
```

But this is not a good approach either... Can you think of anything better?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the answer you're looking for, but I think the best practice in this case would be to use webpack to uglify it for production and not worry about loading minified files. Having webpack run uglify on the whole bundle will prune out all unused codepaths then minify it anyways.

Comment: There is a lib named phaser which has different files. The default comes with many other tools in it. But it also has other files that has only what I need. The whole file is +1MB the part I need is like 300KB. What do you suggest?

Comment: I would stick with letting webpack minify the rest like moment, lodash, and react, but for phaser, I think you should probably use an alias just because of it's size. It'll slow down your build operations. if you uglify after you bundle, the resulting output file will be the same, but it's just an issue of build time.

Comment: I have the same concern, webpack is meant to get rid of many files being loaded asynchronously in browser, but the drawaback is that you end with a very big file. It's a shame that this question is not popular. A lot of people is using webpack and a lot of people should have this concerns.